# AngularJS route and ngview not working

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am preparing a simple demo using AngularJS `$route` and `ng-view`, see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/techprasad/b2pr0ndx/1/)

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/leftMenu', { templateUrl: 'partials/leftMenu.html', controller: 'dashboardCtrl'})
    .when('/leftMenuCategoryProducts', { templateUrl: 'partials/leftMenu2.html', controller: 'dashboardCtrl2'});
```

but it is not currently working.

Comment: @Tom, Thanks, I updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/techprasad/b2pr0ndx/2/

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of things wrong with your fiddle:

- You're not injecting `$locationProvider`, but you're trying to call `$locationProvider.html2mode(true)`, which brings us to:
- You're calling `$locationProvider.html2mode(true)` instead of `$locationProvider.html5mode(true)`
- You're never declaring your app in your markup, i.e., `ng-app="onlineStoreApp"`
- You never include `angular-route.js`, so you're getting errors that it cannot be found
- You're just passing your routing function as a 3rd parameter to the module declaration instead of passing it into a `.config()`

Here is an updated example of what it might look like:

Markup:

```
<div ng-app="onlineStoreApp">
    <a href="/leftMenu">Menu</a>
    <a href="/leftMenuCategoryProducts">Category</a>
    <a href="/leftMenuCategoryProducts">Category</a>

    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular
    .module('onlineStoreApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider
            .when('/leftMenu', { templateUrl: 'partials/leftMenu.html', controller: 'dashboardCtrl'})
            .when('/leftMenuCategoyProducts', { templateUrl: 'partials/leftMenu2.html', controller: 'dashboardCtrl2'});
    });
```